# Uninitialized constant error in rails initializer when running rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, bower

I am having an issue with the bower-rails initializer when running rspec. The gems I am using are rspec-rails and bower-rails. Both have been set up and installed using the relevant generators as detailed on their respective github accounts.

My gem versions are rails (4.1.4), bower-rails (0.8.3), and rspec-rails (3.0.2).

If I create a simple model using a generator, and attempt to do bundle exec rspec, I get the following output:

```
app/config/initializers/bower_rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant BowerRails (NameError)
```

If you set up a simple application and install only those two gems, generate a simple model, and try running rspec, you should be able to reproduce the error. This is particularly frustrating, because I really like both gems and would rather keep both in my workflow. Any help or insight is greatly appreciated. I guess I can remove bower-rails if no alternative solution can be found.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.4'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'spring', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

gem 'bower-rails', group: :development
```

SOLVED: Changing the last line in the Gemfile above to simply gem 'bower-rails' seems to make rspec happy.

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: I actually found a "solution". If you change the line in the above Gemfile from gem 'bower-rails', group: :development to just gem 'bower-rails', then the problem disappears.

Comment: ```gem 'bower-rails'``` must be available in all environments.